# Add custom Select to contact form Magento 2 - Theme Luma

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, forms, luma-theme, contact-form

following other guides, I added in the page form to

**/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml**

and I added the code

```
<div class="field selezione required">
        <label class="label" for="subject"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Come hai conosciuto AvaloItalia?') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <select selectname="selezione" id="selezione" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Come hai conosciuto AvaloItalia?') ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" value="ciao">
              <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
              <option value="google">Google</option>
              <option value="altro">Altro</option>
            </select>               
        </div>
    </div>
```

I adjusted the template that I get email but the field is always empty.

```
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}
{{trans "Come hai conosciuto AvalonItalia?: %selezione" selezione=$data.selezione}}
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
```

**What am I doing wrong? how can i fix it?**

Comment: Could you share what variable you have added in your email template ?

Comment: I went into Marketing-> Email Templates and I created a new model using the default one, I added the variable {{trans "Come hai conosciuto AvalonItalia?: %selezione" selezione=$data.selezione}} and I used this template as default. I modify question with code Template Email.

Comment: Don't update the core modules files, you have to override the `module-contact`then you update the phtml as you need in a new one !

Comment: how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in Magento 2.2.X

1) Put this in your app/design/frontend/[theme-provider]/[theme-name]/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml and modify it to your liking, for example add a new select box as follows:

```
<div class="field region input-box">
                <label for="dropdown"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Region') ?></span></label>
                <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
                    <option value="selected">select…</option>
                    <option name="retail" value="Retail">Retail</option>
                    <option name="wholesale" value="Wholesale">Wholesale</option>
                    <option name="customerservice" value="CustomerService">Customer Service</option>
                    <option name="logistics" value="logistics">Logistics</option>
                    <option name="general" value="General">General</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

2) Run this code:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

3) In your dashboard go to **> Marketing > Email Templates**, you need to create a new template  if you don't have one

4) In Load default template choose a template in this case  **Contact Form** and click on the button Load Template.

5) Add a name to the template.

6) In template content Open a space in the code and place this:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>{{trans "Region"}}</b></td>
    <td>{{var data.dropdown}}</td>
</tr>
```

7) in your dashboard go to **> STORES > Configuration > General Contacts > Email Options > Email Template**, choose your new email template and save.

Comment: This returns the option value for me. Is there any way to return the label instead?

Comment: Thank you man! It worked like a charm!