# Magento2: Dropdown option in contact page

Tags: magento2, contact-us

We add custom option in contact page:

```
<div class="field ordernumber">
                            <div class="control">
                                <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Order Number') ?>" name="ordernumber" id="ordernumber"
                                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                       echo __('Order Number') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                        <div class="field rodzajzgloszenia">
                <div class="control">
                    <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Rodzaj zgloszenia') ?>" name="rodzajzgloszenia" id="rodzajzgloszenia"
                           title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           echo __('Rodzaj zgloszenia') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

email Template:

```
<tr>
           <td><strong>{{trans "Order Number"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.ordernumber}}</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
           <td><strong>{{trans "Rodzaj zgloszenia"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.rodzajzgloszenia}}</td>
    </tr>
```

But how to create in field: `Rodzaj zgłoszenia` dropdown with select option and forward in email selected option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this file form.phtml and write the code :-

```
<div class="field region input-box">
                <label for="dropdown"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Region') ?></span></label>
                <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
                    <option value="selected">select…</option>
                    <option name="retail" value="Retail">Retail</option>
                    <option name="wholesale" value="Wholesale">Wholesale</option>
                    <option name="customerservice" value="CustomerService">Customer Service</option>
                    <option name="logistics" value="logistics">Logistics</option>
                    <option name="general" value="General">General</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

After run the command :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

And last add this code your contact email Template

```
<tr>
    <td><b>{{trans "Region"}}</b></td>
    <td>{{var data.dropdown}}</td>
</tr>
```

And more useful link :-

**[Add custom Select to contact form Magento 2 - Theme Luma](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/218935/add-custom-select-to-contact-form-magento-2-theme-luma)**

Hope this help

Thanks ...